# How to create an (image) Header logo with MVC(4)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, header, actionlink, graphical-logo

I'm struggling with an Razor syntax with MVC (4), hoping to find someone who can help me with a nice and working solution.

I want a clickable logo(image) and created the following code. This works except of two things. I don't see the image display and secondly, when in an other controller, the routing goes wrong (http4 error).

This is how i've done it now:

**Razor:**

```
<h1>@Html.ActionLink("siteHeader", "Index", null, new { @class = "site-logo"})</h1>
```

*OR*

```
<h1>@Html.ActionLink("siteHeader", "Index", "Home", new { @class = "site-logo"})</h1>
```

e.g. when in a different controller (account/shoppingcart/etc.) and clicking the logo, it results in a 404.

**CSS:**

/*Site HeaderLogo*/

```
a.site-logo  {     
 background: url(images/Solosoft.png) no-repeat top left;
 display: block;       
 width: 100px;       
 height: 100px;       
 text-indent: -9999px;  /*hides the link text*/ 
  }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("siteHeader", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "site-logo"})
```

This is:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    Object routeValues,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

Link: [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

Comment: Ok, thanx. I was almost there :P Now, i only have to find out why i don't see the actual image.

Comment: @user1714323 open dev tools in browser and on network tab, I think,  you will see 404 error. Check your url path, now you trying to find images in controller 'folder', like `/Home/images/Solosoft.png`

Comment: Thanks for your support. The problem with the image was that i had to set the measurements correctly in css. I'm up and running now.

Answer (score 1):

I got the problem cause!

theres nothing wrong with our coding, the thing is theres a class that overrides our image set

theres this lines in Site.css

```
.site-title a, .site-title a:hover, .site-title a:active {
    *background: none;* <=comment this out and the bg will show or remove the .site-title a
    color: #c8c8c8;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

What wizzardz said is correct. Background style in custom css file is overridden by styles in site.css.

Try this, `!important` - used to give priority to styles to appear in webpage.

In your custom.css page,

```
a.site-logo  {     
     background: url(images/Solosoft.png) no-repeat top left **!important**;
     display: block;       
     width: 100px;    
     height: 100px;       
     text-indent: -9999px;  /*hides the link text*/ 
}
```

No need to change anything in site.css